# Removing soltuion items from TFS2010 and "action caused a check out of the file(s)..." message

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

My solution structure looks something like this:

```
MySolution
    FirstProject
    SecondProject
    SolutionFolder1
        SolutionFolder2
            SolutionItem1.txt
            SolutionItem2.txt
```

1. Then there are two workspaces with
   this solution at the same version
   used by two users on different
   computers.
2. A solution item is removed in the first workspace and the change is checked in into TFS.
3. In the second workspace the latest version is get from the TFS (the workspace is without local modifications and no files are checked out). Visual Studio displays this message:

> Your action caused a check out of the
>   file(s) C:\MySolution \MySolution.sln,
>   and a new version from source control
>   has been loaded in the development
>   environment.

Now, there are two items in pending changes in the second workspace: solution file is checked out and the solution item is deleted. After undoing these changes and getting latest version, they appear again. These conflicts are resolved only during checkin which is a little bit confusing.

Is there a way how to get rid of this TFS oddity? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any answer but there is a workaround. Solution probably is not the best place to store complex folder hierarchies with a lot of files. When these folders and files are moved to own VS project then everything works well.

Comment: This sorted my issue out.  My issue was:  if an assembly in a solution folder changed on disk (e.g. as a result of a forced get latest) it would check out the solution file.  Moving the files into a project fixed it.